# Co-locating related entities on the same shard

Tags: elasticsearch

How does one co-locate related entities on different indexes (or even different types on the same index), so that they are both on the same shard?

For example, lets say that there are two entity types:

```
Customer

Orders
```

In order to enhance performance, all `Orders` entities related to a specific customer should be located on the same shard as the `Customer` entity itself.

How is this done?

Thanks

Comment: :-) entities from different indexes is out of the question. An index is split into shards. You cannot combine things from one index with things from another index in the same shard.

Comment: To have things colocated, use the same routing key.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what about two entity types on the same index?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly add a [routing value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html) when you index each document so that they are stored on the same shard. This is only possible if the types exist in the same index.